# Group based on date diff without using recursive

Tags: vertica

How to convert below SQL server recursive query in vertica. I know that vertica does not support recursive query. i tried using sum() over with lag but i am still not able to acheive final expected output.

`with Product as (
    select * from (
        VALUES 
(1, '2018-12-25','2019-01-05' ),
(1, '2019-03-01','2019-03-10' ),
(1, '2019-03-15','2019-03-19' ),
(1, '2019-03-22','2019-03-28' ),
(1, '2019-03-30','2019-04-02' ),
(1, '2019-04-10','2019-04-15' ),
(1, '2019-04-18','2019-04-25' )
    ) as a1 (ProductId   ,ProductStartDt   ,ProductEndDt)
), OrderedProduct as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ProductStartDt) as RowNum
    from Product
), DateGroupsInterim (RowNum, GroupNum, GrpStartDt, Indx) as (
    select RowNum, 1, ProductEndDt,1
    from OrderedProduct
    where RowNum=1
    union all 
    select OrderedProduct.RowNum, 
        CASE WHEN OrderedProduct.ProductStartDt <= dateadd(day, 15, dgi.GrpStartDt) 
                THEN dgi.GroupNum 
                ELSE dgi.GroupNum + 1
        END,
        CASE WHEN OrderedProduct.ProductStartDt <= dateadd(day, 15, dgi.GrpStartDt) 
                THEN dgi.GrpStartDt 
                ELSE OrderedProduct.ProductEndDt
        END, 
        CASE WHEN OrderedProduct.ProductStartDt <= dateadd(day, 15, dgi.GrpStartDt) 
                THEN 0 
                ELSE 1
        END
    from DateGroupsInterim dgi
        join OrderedProduct on OrderedProduct.RowNum=dgi.RowNum+1
) select OrderedProduct.ProductId, OrderedProduct.ProductStartDt, OrderedProduct.ProductEndDt, DateGroupsInterim.GrpStartDt, DateGroupsInterim.GroupNum, Indx
from DateGroupsInterim
    JOIN OrderedProduct on OrderedProduct.RowNum = DateGroupsInterim.RowNum
    order by 2`

Below is how the expected output looks like. 
[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 2):

The operation you want to do is also called "sessionization" - which is the operation of splitting a time series into groups/ sub time series that have a certain meaning together.

The way you describe it, it does not seem to be possible:

The next group relies exactly on both the start of its previous group (15 min later than the start of the first row of the previous group) and the end of the previous group's last row. This needs to be a loop or a recursion, which is not offered by Vertica.

I managed to join the table with itself and get a session id for consecutive rows within 15 minutes. But, as of now, they're overlapping, and I found no way to determine which group I want to keep...

Like so:

```
WITH product(productid   ,productstartdt   ,productenddt) AS (                                                                                                       
          SELECT 1, DATE '2018-12-25',DATE '2019-01-05'
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2019-03-01',DATE '2019-03-10'
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2019-03-15',DATE '2019-03-19'
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2019-03-22',DATE '2019-03-28'
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2019-03-30',DATE '2019-04-02'
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2019-04-10',DATE '2019-04-15'
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2019-04-18',DATE '2019-04-25'
)   
,   
groups AS (
SELECT 
  a.productstartdt AS in_productstartdt
, b.* 
, CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(a.productstartdt) OVER(PARTITION BY a.productid ORDER BY a.productstartdt) AS grp 
FROM product a
LEFT JOIN product b
   ON a.productid     = b.productid
  AND a.productstartdt <= b.productstartdt 
  AND (a.productstartdt=b.productstartdt OR b.productstartdt <= a.productenddt + 15) 
)   
SELECT * FROM groups;

-- out  in_productstartdt | productid | productstartdt | productenddt | grp 
-- out -------------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-----
-- out  2018-12-25        |         1 | 2018-12-25     | 2019-01-05   |   0
-- out  2019-03-01        |         1 | 2019-03-01     | 2019-03-10   |   1
-- out  2019-03-01        |         1 | 2019-03-22     | 2019-03-28   |   1
-- out  2019-03-01        |         1 | 2019-03-15     | 2019-03-19   |   1
-- out  2019-03-15        |         1 | 2019-03-15     | 2019-03-19   |   2
-- out  2019-03-15        |         1 | 2019-03-22     | 2019-03-28   |   2
-- out  2019-03-15        |         1 | 2019-03-30     | 2019-04-02   |   2
-- out  2019-03-22        |         1 | 2019-03-22     | 2019-03-28   |   3
-- out  2019-03-22        |         1 | 2019-03-30     | 2019-04-02   |   3
-- out  2019-03-22        |         1 | 2019-04-10     | 2019-04-15   |   3
-- out  2019-03-30        |         1 | 2019-04-10     | 2019-04-15   |   4
-- out  2019-03-30        |         1 | 2019-03-30     | 2019-04-02   |   4
-- out  2019-04-10        |         1 | 2019-04-10     | 2019-04-15   |   5
-- out  2019-04-10        |         1 | 2019-04-18     | 2019-04-25   |   5
-- out  2019-04-18        |         1 | 2019-04-18     | 2019-04-25   |   6
-- out (15 rows)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (15 rows): 35.454 ms. All rows formatted: 35.503 ms
```

What is the next difficulty is how to get rid of grp-s 2, 3, and 5 ....